Output from evaluating python source code blocks in org-mode not correct
After switching to Mac from Windows, the output of my python org-mode code blocks are not working properly. It keeps printing what seems to be the backend python call, and not even the full command, seems to cut the command short (as in the example below the Result stops before the input to the python "print" command).
The code is executing as expected and the results are printed in the interactive python session buffer (still with the annoying backend call at the top though). However, it is not being appended in the org-mode buffer itself. Any tips on how to

Output the actual python outputs in the org-mode buffer
not output the "__PYTHON_EL_eva(...)" part

Here is example code:
#+BEGIN_SRC python :python python3 :session py :results output  :noweb yes :tangle no

print("Somehow the output of these source blocks are not displayed correctly? I did not have this issue with emacs on Windows...")

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: __PYTHON_EL_eval("try:\n    with open('/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/babel-PJfJby/python-HFmx85') as __org_babel_python_tmpfile:\n        exec(compile(__org_babel_python_tmpfile.read(), __org_babel_python_tmpfile.name, 'exec'))\nexcept:\n    raise\nfinally:\n    print('

This is how it looks in the interactive python buffer:
__PYTHON_EL_eval_file("/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/py66QmoC", "/var/folders/ty/x6hl83sn5cz667zpq3yk02lr0000gn/T/py66QmoC", True)
Somehow the output of these source blocks are not displayed correctly? I did not have this issue with emacs on Windows...
org_babel_python_eoe
>>> 

Running Emacs 29.4 on macOS Sonoma 14.4
I have tried to set :results value which returns "None" as expected. I notice this does not print the backend string.
EDIT:
I was pointed to this thread and following the steps provided by Ian fixed the iussue ✅ https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/81683/python-org-babel-producing-garbled-result

[emacs.se] may be a better place to ask questions specific to org-mode.

Good point. I will try that as well, thank you.

Please don't ask in both places: Emacs SE is more appropriate (and in fact, the question is a duplicate there, so there is an answer already), so please close this one.

This issue was similar to what was described here:
Python Org Babel producing garbled result
The answer provided by Ian fixed the issue.
